# ArgumentNullException while dealing with DataTable and DataAdapter in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, sqldataadapter

i am using `DataAdapter` to fill my `DataTable` with query as `Stored Procedure`.
But there is an exception `ArgumentNullException`coming when i try to `Fill` DataTable. I tested the query and its working fine.

Here's my code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["NewsId"] = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["news"]);
                if (Session["NewsId"] != null && Convert.ToInt32(Session["NewsId"]) != 0)
                {
                    id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["NewsId"]);
                }
            }
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("NewsGallerySelect", con);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@NewsID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                rptrNews.DataSource = dt;
                rptrNews.DataBind();
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    lblShrtDesc.Text = row["ShortDesc"].ToString();
                    lblShrtDesc2.Text = row["ShortDesc"].ToString();
                    lblDesc.Text = row["NewsDesc"].ToString();
                    lblDesc2.Text = row["NewsDesc"].ToString();
                    lblDate.Text = row["NewsDate"].ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: I bet you declared `dt` without instantiating it, try `DataTable  dt = new DataTable();`

Comment: @raidensan done. thanks..